# product of arrays of different sizes in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have two arrays, `x = np.arange(3) = [0,1,2,3]` and `y = np.arange(4) = [0,1,2]`.

Is there a numpy function that gives a table of all of their products ?  Or example for times this would be:

```
x*y = [[0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3], [0,2,4,6]]
```

This is not the inner product or the scalar product. This could be called the "tensor product" or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the outer product specifically there is `np.outer`:

```
>>> x = np.arange(3)
>>> y = np.arange(4)
>>> np.outer(x, y)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6]])
>>>
```

More generally you can achieve this with broadcasting:

```
>>> x = np.arange(3)
>>> y = np.arange(4)
>>> x[..., None] * y[None, ...]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6]])
>>>
```

To apply a function with two parameters over all pairs, you would define it as:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x * y
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
>>> f(x[..., None], y[None, ...])
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6]])
>>>
```

To apply a function with one parameter over the outer product you would do:

```
np.exp(np.outer(x, y))
```

or

```
np.exp(x[..., None] * y[None, ...])
```

More on broadcasting:

- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Can `np.outer` be generalize to I get the table `[[f(a,b) for a in x] for b in y]` for arbitrary function `f(x,y)`?

Comment: Without `np.outer` numpy was complaining that I multiplied matrices of two different sizes.  In fact, I was using `*` which like an inner product.  I wound up using some slower method with list comprehensions.

Comment: Your comment worked `f(np.outer(x,y))`.  In my case, `f = np.exp`.